# Global context for next js

Tags: next.js14

I want to create a global context for my Next.js 14 project without relying on Redux. The data stored in this context should be accessible throughout the entire application.  I am a new web developer seeking guidance.

I used next-auth. Though it provided global context for session but i couldn't set anything else there.